# Nested XML Parsing using c#

Tags: c#, xml

Cracking my head to parse out this nested xml, im using the XmlNodeList lists = doc.SelectNodes method, problem is it cannot go to the next DRSites node.

```
<FileInfo>
  <DRSites>
    <ASite>X3Os</ASite>
    <SSite>SS</SSite>
    <tots>
      <tot>
        <totno>abx12</totno>
      </tot>
      <tot>
        <totno>cde</totno>
      </tot>
    </tots>
  </DRSites>
  <DRSites>
      <ASite>xya</ASite>
      <SSite>mne</SSite>
      <tots>
        <tot>
          <totno>ew34</totno>
        </tot>
        <tot>
          <totno>fdf5435</totno>
        </tot>
      </tots>
    </DRSites>
</FileInfo>
```

CODE: 
my code (which not woking, only loop through tots but didnt get the correct edrsite

```
 XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("/FileInfo/DRSites"); // get all <testcase> nodes
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodelist) // for each <testcase> node
            {
                try
                {
                    string AssySite = node.SelectSingleNode("ASite").InnerText;
                    string SortSite = node.SelectSingleNode("SSite").InnerText;

                    XmlNodeList nodelist2 = doc.SelectNodes("tots/tot"); // get all <testcase> nodes
                     foreach (XmlNode node2 in nodelist2)
                     {
                         AssySite = node2.SelectSingleNode("totno").InnerText;       

                     }
                }
```

Comment: why not use GetElementsByTagName?

Comment: Thats some cool looking xml there. Can we have some code with it?

Comment: Welcome to S.O! :) Could you please read through this document on [asking questions on the site](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? Please post your code, so people can help you easier. Heads up for the indenting and pasting of the xml though =).

Comment: You want to get all DRSites nodes right?

Comment: What did you mean by *only loop through loop but didnt get the correct edrsite*?

Comment: what i mean is i need it to lopp trough DRsites node and then lots node. But now it's getting ; under first DRSite, it will get correct Asite & Ssite, but it will loop thru tots that are out side of the first DRSite node. it;s not following hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq to XML. Parse xml string, or Load from file and you can things like:

```
var DRSiteElements = XElement.Parse(xml).Descendants("DRSites").ToList();
```

Comment: I was able to loop through tots and get the totno. But then for each tots fragment it cannot get correct DRsites... Im using the one with foreach node in nodelist